# ReactJS installation and overkill complexity

Tags: javascript, html

Can somebody give possible simple explanation how to install the ReactJS from the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/installation.html#adding-react-to-an-existing-application).

What are importan JS files in package react-16.2.0?
And what means:

```
C:\Users\myuser>npm install --save react react-dom
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\myuser\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\myuser\package.json'
npm WARN myuser No description
npm WARN myuser No repository field.
npm WARN myuser No README data
npm WARN myuser No license field.

+ react@16.2.0
+ react-dom@16.2.0
added 18 packages in 4.919s
```

And I don't never understand why such excelent projects including reactjs are made in a many thousand files instead of one javascript file like jQuery. It makes the pacakge using too much difficult that i prefer not begin to learn such technologies. Such new programming tools have to be possible simple installable.

Comment: You need to be within an npm project to use that command. Use `npm init` to initialise the empty project, cd into that project. The directory should now have a `package.json` file. You should then be able to run your original command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run react without using Babel and Webpack by using CDN which is how you use jquery. You just have to add

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

But the problem with this is you will not get JSX. Which means you'll have to write

```
return React.createElement('h1', null, 'Greetings, ' + this.props.name + '!');
```

which is vanilla javascript, instead of writing

`return (
  <h1>Greetings, {this.props.name}!</h1>
);`

The second code piece is JSX with which you can kind of write HTML within JS. 
Babel is a transpiler which converts JSX to vanilla javascript. It also adds ES6 features which some browsers might not support.

Webpack is a code-bundler. It bundles all the code together for production and also helps in live reloading of the code. If you're starting out in react i would recommend you use create-react-app. It basically does all the configuration and comes preinstalled with babel and webpack. 
[Create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

```
npm install -g create-react-app

create-react-app my-app
cd my-app/
npm start
```

The errors in your app is because you haven't initialised the folder, which can be done by running `npm init` before you install react and react-dom.